# replace list element by id, overwrite it and update DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a list of elements, each one targeting a file like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="G367" class="list-group-item">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">2015-10-21-1445461638-8821023-ag_0666.jpeg</button>
    (...)
    <li id="G366" class="list-group-item btn btn-secondary">
    (...)
  </li>
</ul>
```

In **dropdown actions** I got for each a **replace function** which delete the file and replace it with a new one.

I thought of updating the row by replacing the `contentText` and also the `id` attribute of the row. Apparently it works but **the DOM is not updated** and keep tracking the old id.

Reading further, I've seen it's not recommended to change IDs. I don't understand why. How would one replace lines in this case?

Here is the `js` I use:

```
// Replace file

$(document).on('submit', '#replace-file', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: this.action,
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        }).done(function (resp) {
        $('#' + resp.old_ref)[0].firstElementChild.textContent = resp.data;
        $('#' + resp.old_ref).attr('id', resp.new_ref);

        $('#form-modal').modal('toggle');
    });
});
```

Comment: destroy the entire element and replace with a new one with correct id, var li =  $('#' + resp.old_ref); li.parent.append("<li id='" + resp.new_ref + "'>" + resp.data + "</li>"); li.remove();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

destroy the entire element and replace with a new one with correct id:

```
var li =  $('#' + resp.old_ref); 
li.closest("ul").append("<li id='" + resp.new_ref + "'>" + resp.data + "</li>"); 
li.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

Try this

```
$('#' + resp.old_ref)[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML= resp.data;
```